# Check values against a set of allowed values

Tags: pyspark

I want to check values in one table against a mapping table.

**Data Table:**

| ID | Color | Object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Green | Grass |
| 002 | Green | Tree |
| 003 | Green | Sky |
| 004 | Green | Apple |
| 005 | Red | Apple |
| 006 | Red | Poppy |
| 007 | Red | Water |

**Allowed Mappings**

| MappingID | MappingKey | MappingValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M001 | Green | Grass |
| M002 | Green | Tree |
| M003 | Green | Apple |
| M004 | Red | Apple |
| M005 | Red | Poppy |

The expected output is the entries that are *not* foreseen in the mapping table.

**Output:**

| ID | Color | Object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 003 | Green | Sky |
| 007 | Red | Water |

Here are the **dataframe definitions** so you can get started more easily:

```
data_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("001", "Green", "Grass"),
        ("002", "Green", "Tree"),
        ("003", "Green", "Sky"),
        ("004", "Green", "Apple"),
        ("005", "Red", "Apple"),
        ("006", "Red", "Poppy"),
        ("007", "Red", "Water")
    ],
    ["ID", "Color", "Object"],
)


mapping_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("M001", "Green", "Grass"),
        ("M002", "Green", "Tree"),
        ("M003", "Green", "Apple"),
        ("M004", "Red", "Apple"),
        ("M005", "Red", "Poppy")
    ],
    ["MappingID", "MappingKey", "MappingValue"],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left_anti` join.

```py
join_on=[
    data_df.Color == mapping_df.MappingKey,
    data_df.Object == mapping_df.MappingValue
]
df = data_df.join(mapping_df, on=join_on, how='left_anti')
```